# Python: parsing sections of a log file

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I have a section of a log file that looks like this:

```
"/log?action=End&env=123&id=8000&cat=baseball"
"/log?action=start&get=3210&rsa=456&key=golf"
```

I want to parse out each section so the results would look like this:

```
('/log?action=', 'End', 'env=123', 'id=8000', 'cat=baseball')
('/log?action=', 'start', 'get=3210', 'rsa=456', 'key=golf')
```

I've looked into regex and matching, but a lot of my logs have different sequences which leads me to believe that it is not possible. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

This is clearly a fragment of a URL, so the best way to parse it is to use URL parsing tools. The stdlib comes with [`urlparse`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/urlparse.html), which does exactly what you want.

For example:

```
>>> import urlparse
>>> s = "/log?action=End&env=123&id=8000&cat=baseball"
>>> bits = urlparse.urlparse(s)
>>> variables = urlparse.parse_qs(bits.query)
>>> variables
{'action': ['End'], 'cat': ['baseball'], 'env': ['123'], 'id': ['8000']}
```

---

If you really want to get the format you asked for, you can use `parse_qsl` instead, and then join the key-value pairs back together. I'm not sure why you want the `/log` to be included in the first query variable, or the first query variable's value to be separate from its variable, but even that is doable if you insist:

```
>>> variables = urlparse.parse_qsl(s)
>>> result = (variables[0][0] + '=', variables[0][1]) + tuple(
    '='.join(kv) for kv in variables[1:])
>>> result
('/log?action=', 'End', 'env=123', 'id=8000', 'cat=baseball')
```

---

If you're using Python 3.x, just change the `urlparse` to `urllib.parse`, and the rest is exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can split a couple times:

```
s = '/log?action=End&env=123&id=8000&cat=baseball'
L = s.split("&")
L[0:1]=L[0].split("=")
```

Output:

```
['/log?action', 'End', 'env=123', 'id=8000', 'cat=baseball']
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to say without knowing what the domain of possible inputs is, but here's a guess at what will work for you:

```
log = "/log?action=End&env=123&id=8000&cat=baseball\n/log?action=start&get=3210&rsa=456&key=golf"

logLines = [line.split("&") for line in log.split('\n')]
logLines = [tuple(line[0].split("=")+line[1:]) for line in logLines]

print logLines
```

OUTPUT:

```
[('/log?action', 'End', 'env=123', 'id=8000', 'cat=baseball'), 
 ('/log?action', 'start', 'get=3210', 'rsa=456', 'key=golf')]
```

This assumes that you don't really need the "=" at the end of the first string.